# fetching one value from each key in an associated array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have the following array

```
array(
    'messages' => array(
        0 => array(
            'id' => '3',
            'subject' => 'what did you say last night?',
            'message' => 'your mother wai',
            'from' => '13',
            'to' => '1',
            'from_viewed' => '0',
            'to_viewed' => '0',
            'from_deleted' => '0',
            'to_deleted' => '0',
            'from_vdate' => NULL,
            'to_vdate' => NULL,
            'from_ddate' => NULL,
            'to_ddate' => NULL,
            'created' => '2016-05-14 14:02:12',
        ) ,
        1 => array(
            'id' => '2',
            'subject' => 'this is new',
            'message' => 'hello guy',
            'from' => '11',
            'to' => '1',
            'from_viewed' => '0',
            'to_viewed' => '0',
            'from_deleted' => '0',
            'to_deleted' => '0',
            'from_vdate' => NULL,
            'to_vdate' => NULL,
            'from_ddate' => NULL,
            'to_ddate' => NULL,
            'created' => '2016-05-14 13:59:56',
        ) ,
        2 => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'subject' => 'hello boy.',
            'message' => 'i love this too much . what do you think about making this happen for tomorrow? already then . good bye',
            'from' => '11',
            'to' => '1',
            'from_viewed' => '0',
            'to_viewed' => '0',
            'from_deleted' => '0',
            'to_deleted' => '0',
            'from_vdate' => NULL,
            'to_vdate' => NULL,
            'from_ddate' => NULL,
            'to_ddate' => NULL,
            'created' => '2016-05-14 13:54:02',
        ) ,
    ) ,
)
```

All i want to do is to take the 'FROM' value of every key in the array(in this case it is - 13, 11 ,11) and then send them to the database to retrieve information like their name and avatar , in codeigniter.

UPDATE

I TRIED THE FOLLOWING AND IT GAVE ME 11,11,13, (with a comma at the back).

```
 $from  =  $messages['messages'];


      for ($col = 0; $col < 3; $col++) {
        echo $messages['messages'][$col]['from'].",";
      }
```

Besides , i dont want to determine how many values it should echo. I want it to echo as  long as it exists.

Comment: you put here `var_dump()` array. Please provide `var_export()` array, so that we can test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may use this

```
$t = array(
    'messages' => array()
 )
 /// your array ......

$from = '';
foreach($t['messages'] as $k => $m){
    if($k == 0){
        $from = $m['from'];
    }else{
        $from .= ','.$m['from'];
    }
}
echo $from;
```

It will output as `13,11,11`. But if you need array of those values then you may use following

```
$from = array();
foreach($t['messages'] as $k => $m){
        $from[] = $m['from'];

}
print_r($from);
```

Comment: Vote up. Alternatively, you can offer `$from[$k]` to have binded concrete message key.

Comment: thanks but this  ` $t = array(
                'messages' => array()
             );
             /// your array ......

          $from = $messages['messages'];
foreach($t['messages'] as $k => $m){
        $from[] = $m['from'];

}
print_r($from); ` only  prints an empty array - array();

Comment: the following one prints  **13,13.** `$t = array(
                'messages' => array()
             );
             /// your array ......

            $from = $messages['messages'][0]['from'];
            foreach($t['messages'] as $k => $m){
                if($k == 0){
                    $from = $m['from'];
                }else{
                    $from .= ','.$m['from'];
                }
            }

            echo $from;

            print_r($from);`  . would be nice to combine the value into an array so i can send it to the database for processing please. thanks

Comment: you may use first solution and then explode the result to make array. `$final_arr = explode(',',$from);`

Comment: WORKED NOW. HAD TO DO A FEW TWEAKING!